# how to save text to file in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio

I want to create file in which the first line will be constantly updated. actually I want to save this file to custom path, for example /storage/emulated/0/Download, but I don't know how to do that, so now I have something like this:

```
public void save(){
    while(true) {
        try {
            String FILENAME = "my_file";
            String string = "" + System.currentTimeMillis();

            FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write(string.getBytes());
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
}
```

and this code gives me two errors

1. Cannot resolve method 'openFileOutput'
2. Cannot resolve symbol 'MODE_PRIVATE'

Comment: The class you're using is not a descendant of the `Context` class, which is why you don't have those symbols available. Perhaps passing an instance of a Context class into the save function and using that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 FileOutputStream fos = getApplicationContext().getContextResolver().openFileOutput(FILENAME);
```

Before using `openFileOutpout()` you have to use `getContextResolver()` and there is no `Context.MODE_PRIVATE` parameter in this function